# is there any way to "reset" the csrf token after successful login?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I just enabled the csrf token protection on my spring security (with xml) by adding the csrf tag.

It works great but I noticed when I hit the login form I am sending a csrf token, after a successful login the csrf token is still the same, is there anyway I can reset it after hit the login form?

After checking the docs I found no clue how to do this or if is due my repository? (Im not using any custom csrf repository)

Ideas?

Comment: after a valid token is generated, the token before login will still be a valid token, meaning I exposed it to a non authenticated user and they will know on the restricted pages what token is :)

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-timeouts) states that the CSRF token is stored in the `HttpSession` by default. Since the token is stored in the session, it will continue to get reused after the user has logged in.

If you really want to reset the token on a successful login, you will have to handle successful login events.

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessCsrfTokenResetHandler
             extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
  private final CsrfTokenRepository repository;

  public AuthenticationSuccessCsrfTokenResetHandler(final CsrfTokenRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request
                                      , final HttpServletResponse response
                                      , final Authentication authentication)
                                      throws ServletException, IOException {
      repository.saveToken(repository.generateToken(request), request, response)
  }
}
```

Then, configure this handler in your Spring Security configuration.

Comment: Thanks @manish! this would be a normal bean or do I have to implement a filter?

Comment: This is a regular bean. See [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-form-target) for configuring the success handler. No filter needs to be overridden or added.